# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory - Command line

Tags: java, ftp

I am trying to run a jar which will download file from FTP server to my local machine, and as per the user manual there is ftpcourier.jar containing the class file to perform the task.
as per user manual I prepared a command but I am getting NoClassDefFoundError on console.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin>java  -Demail-conf-path=d:\config -jar ftpcourier.jar -d RCVE -h test.hostname.com -u smandal -w Password# -f /TIFR/report.xls -t d:\Local -s true -p 22 -x true
```

getting error on console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/
    at com.dmainc.commons.stuff.ftp.FTPCourier.<clinit>(FTPCourier
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.loggin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:30
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

I have added commons-logging-1.1.1.jar full path in environment variable.
Any suggestions pls.

Answer (score 0):

you should not add it in environment variable, instead of that you can add that path in the command line itself. give the directory path in the command like this. * means it will take all the jars in the given path

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin>java -cp .;<path>\*;  -Demail-conf-path=d:\config -jar ftpcourier.jar -d RCVE -h test.hostname.com -u smandal -w Password# -f /TIFR/report.xls -t d:\Local -s true -p 22 -x true
```

Comment: Still not working...I have placed my all jars including ftpcourier and commons in one folder and ran command ..C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre>java -cp .;D:\task\ftpcourier\*  -Demail-conf-path=d:\config -jar ftpcourier.jar -d RCVE -h test.hostname.com -u smandal -w Password# -f /TIFR/report.xls -t d:\Local -s true

Comment: it should be D:\task\ftpcourier\*